# Pseudo selector :has() removes effect

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a presentation using reveal.js (from Quarto) and would like to tweak the CSS a bit. Here, I would like to add a margin to a certain div if it is followed by a paragraph.

Without the `:has()` pseudo selector, there is a visible effect:

```css
div.cell {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

However, when I add it, there is no effect whatsoever:

```css
div.cell:has(+ p) {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this might be the case? I know a bit of plain vanilla CSS, otherwise my understanding is limited. But the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) documentation seems to suggest that my code should work...

Below is a screenshot of the div element I would like to target. I'm using an up-to-date version of Firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using an up-to-date version of Firefox.

Firefox [currently does not have support for `:has`](https://caniuse.com/css-has) (it looks like it is due to land in Firefox 121 which is due [December 2023](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Release_Management/Calendar&redirect=no)).

It is available behind a [feature flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features) and enabled by default in [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly).

Details of the state of the feature are available in the [Firefox bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039).

Comment: Oh, that's crazy. Are there any other workarounds? So basically I would have to add the margin to the paragraph if it is preceded by `div.cell`, i.e., `div.cell + p`?